# List files in directory recursively and what they contain

Tags: centos, files, file-search

I'm trying to find all the values stored in files in a directory.

I can `cat /some/dir/*` but that just gets me something like

```
1
2
3
4
```

What I want is something like

```
/some/dir/file1: 1
/some/dir/file2: 2
```

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all files contain only one line:

```
find /some/dir -type f -exec awk '{print FILENAME ": " $0}' {} +
```

Else, print a single line with the filename as header:

```
find /some/dir -type f -exec awk 'FNR<2{print FILENAME ":"}1' {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `grep` (which happens to be the implementation found on CEntOS) or compatible:

```
grep -r '^' /some/dir
```

The `^` regular expression matches at the start of each line, so matches every line. `grep` prepends the file name to each matching line. You can also add the `-n` option to include line numbers.

POSIXly:

```
find /some/dir -type f -exec grep '^' /dev/null {} +
```

We add `/dev/null` to make sure `grep` prints the file name even if the list of files has only one element.